# TinyMCE - how to change sub-indent items from number to letter

Tags: tinymce

We are using TinyMCE and have allowed bulleted lists, numbered lists, plus indent and outdent buttons.  If a user creates a numbered list **within** a numbered list, is there a way I can make TinyMCE insert 'a', 'b', 'c' etc instead of numbers at the sub-indented level?

For example, I would like to see this:

1. something
2. something

   a. something

   b. something

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is a way. Use the 'Increase indent' button on a given list item then click on the 'Numbered list' drop down menu and choose 'Lower alpha'.